# How to modify Bootstrap's LESS variables in a Flask app?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, sass, less

I am making a static website with Flask and using the flask-bootstrap extension to simplify the front-end development. I concurrently have been learning Rails and so I understand that there are a few of these languages that compile down to CSS (LESS/SASS/SCSS). As I understand it, Bootstrap by default uses LESS, and in my Rails app I had to convert LESS variables (with an @ symbol at the beginning) into SCSS variables (with a $). This wasn't too difficult, no problem.

I noticed that in Miguel Grinberg's tutorial (Flask Web Development, O'Reilly) Bootstrap is used (Flask-Bootstrap extension), and there is the brief mention of {% block styles %} used to include stylesheets that way, I am confused about how I can go about modifying the existing LESS variables that come by default with Bootstrap so that I can modify the grid structure and not mess things up with my own custom stylesheets. I want to be able to do, for example, is modify the @body-bg LESS variable, or any of the ones here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize

Comment: You don't have to convert `Less` version to `Sass`. Twitter bootstrap has already an official Sass port: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

It is very interesting question. I also was interesting in creating styles dynamically. You need follow another ways. It is not possible by the way you have described above.

You mentioned you used Flask-Bootstrap. This extension adopts the Flask project to use the Twitter Bootstrap styles. I have not fond any SASS/LESS functionality.
http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/#
https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap

If you look at the static folder of the extension you will not find any tracks of SASS/LESS.

As I know Twitter Bootstrap is generated by LESS. There is also a SASS fork. You regenerate styles and replace them in the static folder of the Flask-Bootstrap project.

If you want to do it dynamically you need create your own solution.  I do not know a ready extension. It is the very challenging task.